# Error: Cannot find module \node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v8.0-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node'

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron, node-sqlite3

I have trouble with installing sqlite3 in electron 8.1
I got following errors

```
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\TASK(2020.1.1~)\AMS\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v8.1-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node'
Require stack:
- D:\TASK(2020.1.1~)\AMS\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js
- D:\TASK(2020.1.1~)\AMS\main.js
- D:\TASK(2020.1.1~)\AMS\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js
-
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:798:15)
    at Function../lib/common/reset-search-paths.ts.Module._resolveFilename (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:7595:16)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:691:27)
    at Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:853:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\TASK(2020.1.1~)\AMS\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:10)
```

I installed `npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source --runtime=electron --target=8.0.2 --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron`
But no luck.  Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out and solved.
needed to followings

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "package": "electron-packager . --production"
  },
```

after that, `npm run postinstall`
it worked for me.

Comment: It's not working for me. Can you please provide an explanation on how it works?

Comment: what was the issue?  after npm run postinstall, could you try npm install ?