# Cannot find module 'E:\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node'

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron

I am developing an electron application using the sqlite3 module and I have developed the code related to function separately now after everything is done now I am trying to import that separately developed module to my main.js file but it's throwing an error from require

> Cannot find module 'E:\CSV-CONVERTOR\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node'

now I have tried so many solutions i'am attaching the solution I have tried below

[1st one](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/906),

[2nd one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60646719/error-cannot-find-module-node-modules-sqlite3-lib-binding-electron-v8-0-win32)

[3rd one](https://discuss.atom.io/t/sqlite3-cannot-find-node-sqlite3-node-question/16530)

[4th one](https://forum.ghost.org/t/unable-to-install-ghost-locall-on-windows-10/18768)

but still after trying everything still it's giving same errors this is the result
[image]

if there is any solution really appriceate the help!

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
```

this is the import of the sqlite package witch working perfectly when i run

```
node process.js
```

this one is working perefectly but when i try to run this in main.js (in electron) it's gave me this errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok after several searches I have found the method now first you have to run

```
npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild
```

then next you have to install sqlite3 if it's already installed you don't have to

```
npm install --save sqlite3
```

Then add this line to

> package.json

Then run this line of code

```
"rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3"
```

Now after doing this you will get a node in your sqlite lib

```
/.../node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/electron-v1.4-darwin-x64/node_sqlite3.node
```

the only thing that I had to do is the change the folder name most of the time it says electron-{your-version}-darwin-x64 instead of the actual version so you have to navigate to this path `node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/` and rename according to you version mine was napi-v6-win32-x64 so you have to rename it